# How do you use query.filters.FulllName._contains on the Directory Model

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

### GOAL

If you want to query and filter FullNames from the Directory Model, how do you do it? Can `filters.FullName._contains =` be used?

### What I've Tried

I've tried this in the Directory Model's Server Script. This returns all the GSuite records, cool.

```
var gQ = app.models.GSuite.newQuery();
gQ.filters.FullName._contains = '';  // filter empty string
var recs = gQ.run();
return recs; // returns all records
```

When I change the filter string to a character, I get no records.

```
var gQ = app.models.GSuite.newQuery();
gQ.filters.FullName._contains = 'a';  // filter the letter a
var recs = gQ.run();
return recs; // returns - recs undefined
```

### Question

What is wrong with the `string` I assign to `filters.FullName._contains =`?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *This returns all the GSuite records, cool.* Probably because there are no entries in your cloud directory with `FullName` filled.

Comment: TheMaster, your thought makes sense. But, this GSuite account has ~100 users with their FullName entered. One way to check this, is to use `https://contacts.google.com/directory` within ones domain. Also, I use `filters.FullName._equals =` to return data with no trouble.

Comment: I see that there are [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory#user_fields_and_query_operators) but `contains` doesn't seem to be one of them. May be you should try a word instead of a letter?

Comment: TheMaster, that was a great suggestion. When I change the `string` to names I know (e.g., my name `'Chadd'`) a proper record is returned. So, it seems `_contains` works differently than I expected.

Comment: Seems, I will need to loop through all the records and use Javascript to parse the FullName strings for characters instead of using App Maker's `query.filters.FIELD._contains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Case Sensitive Solution

This script filters the Directory Model using a Custom Parameter, but it does not use `filters.FullName._contains =`.

Instead, using Javascript's `search()`, each FullName get's a RegEx evaluation. `if (rec.FullName.search(eFilter) > -1))`

**Server Script for Directory Model**

```
var gQ = app.models.GSuite.newQuery();
var gD = gQ.run();

if (query.parameters.FilteredGSuiteEmail === null) {
  return gD; // return all records
}

var eFilter = query.parameters.FilteredGSuiteEmail;
console.info("eFilter: " + eFilter);

var recs = [];
gD.forEach(function(rec) {
  console.log("searchValue: " + rec.FullName.search(eFilter));
  //console.log("search: " + rec.FullName);
  if(rec.FullName.search(eFilter) > -1) {
    console.log("search: " + rec.FullName);
    var newRec = app.models.GSuite.newRecord();
    newRec.FullName = rec.FullName;
    newRec.PrimaryEmail = rec.PrimaryEmail;
    recs.push(newRec);    
  }
});
return recs;
```

I need to convert my filter string to a RegEx argument that is case-insensitive.

***Is there a better way to do this?***